# I want to access dom even in a modal with React-slick (useRef)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-slick

Currently, I'm using react-slick to implement it.
I want to access the slider dom with useref (ref.cuurent), but the moment the modal opens, it becomes null.
You can access it by sliding it.
I think it's probably because I'm accessing it within a modal.
How do I get a ref.cuurent the moment the modal opens?

```
export const index: React.FC = () => {
    const [isShowHowToModal, setIsHowToModal] = useState(true)

    return (
        <Box>
            <div>hello</div>
            {isShowHowToModal && <Modal setIsHowToModal={setIsHowToModal} />}
        </Box>
    )
}
```

```
import Slider from 'react-slick'

export const Modal = React.FC<Props>(setIsModal) => {
  
  const onClickCancel = () => {
    setIsModal(false)
  }

  const refs = useRef<Slider>(null)
  console.log(refs)

  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  }

  return (
    <Slider ref={refs} {...settings}>
      <div>aaa</div>
      <div>bbb</div>
      <div>ccc</div>
    </Slider>
}
```

It would be helpful if you could answer with the function component.

Comment: Hi. Could you please clarify, are you trying to access Slider DOM Node or Slider instance?

Comment: Yes. But the first time I can't access the dom.

Comment: Sorry, it's an "or" question, you answered "Yes" which just made it more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the ref inside useEffect hook, right now you logging it on the first render **before** the Slider is rendered.

#### EDIT:

In your example you have multiple syntactic errors, they might or might not be the reason you have a problem. Anyway check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-lake-im9g0?file=/src/App.tsx), take a look at console, it successfully logs the `refs`.

Sidenote: *If you exporting React.FC named `index` and using it like this `<index> </index>` it won't render the component, but instead will try to find and "index" dom element.*

Comment: Thank you!!I checked  refs by using useEffect.  But it was null.

Comment: @hina, edited the answer, take a look

Comment: Thank you!!
I found someone with the same problem. Please check here. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18032　　                                                      
I found that it can be solved by set timeout. But I don't want to use settimeout.